# Lightbox plugin with zoom in/out buttons?

Tags: modal-dialog, zooming, lightgallery

Have a site with bootstrap/jquery and want to find a script for opening single or group of images pictures (like the bootsrap modal with a 'x' to close or clicking the overlay -outside the image) which i find plenty but none i could find with zoom in /out buttons, and ofc responsive/mobile friendly. Any suggestions?